# how to don't display duplicate with left join

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 4 tables:

```
client: (id, organisme, nom, adresse)

lot: (idLot, id, objetLot, prix)

option: (idOption,idLot,id,prixOption)

variante: (idVariante, idLot, prixVariante)
```

I would like to display all records from `client` with the different `price` about `lot`.

But sometime I got some options on `lot` and or some `variante` on `lot`.

Like this :
[image]

But the problem is that I got this : 
[image]

*I show you my request :*

```
SELECT C.*, L.*, O.*, V.*
FROM 
  client as C
  LEFT JOIN lot as L 
    ON C.id = L.id
  LEFT JOIN option2 as O 
    ON O.id = C.id 
  LEFT JOIN variante as V 
    ON V.id = C.id 
WHERE 
  nomDossier LIKE '%$mc%';
```

Comment: I'd suggest using sqlfiddle for this kind of questions, it really helps a lot

Comment: It's unclear why there are less rows in your desired result than the actual result. What are the rules about which items you want to remove? And why are some of the columns blank? And why does the `prixVariante` value which is actually filled in not match any of the values in the table? Why does one of the `prixOption` values not match any of the values in the table? Are these two even from the same dataset? Are you hoping to Group and Sum some of the values? It's not obvious. Please clarify your intention and your logic.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images. Also notice that short, simple values are easier to get than long, complicate/similar ones. E.g. use `r1` and `r2` instead of `nettyyong ricoacoalere 1` and `nettyyong ricoacoalere 2`.